# how to add command paramaters in QPushButton - PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using a simple GUI with PyQt5 in which I have 3 buttons to record, stop and play the audio. I have some know-how of the Tkinter GUI, but I am totally confused here in PyQt5. In Tkinter Buttons, I am using commands something like this:

```
    record_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Record Audio", command=lambda m=1: threading_rec(m))
    # Stop button
    stop_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Stop Recording", command=lambda m=2: threading_rec(m))
    # Play button
    play_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Play Recording", command=lambda m=3: threading_rec(m))
```

I tried this in Pyqt5 Buttons, but still not working:

```
self.record_btn = QPushButton('Record', self)
        self.record_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.threading_rec(x=1))
        self.record_btn.move(100, 70)

        self.stop_btn = QPushButton('Stop', self)
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.threading_rec(x=2))
        self.stop_btn.move(200, 70)

        self.play_btn = QPushButton('Play', self)
        self.play_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.threading_rec(x=3))
        self.play_btn.move(300, 70)
```

Here is my complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sounddevice as sd
import queue
import soundfile as sf
import threading


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Voice Recorder'
        self.left = 400
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    # Create a queue to contain the audio data
    q = queue.Queue()

    # Declare variables and initialise them
    recording = False
    file_exists = False

    # Fit data into queue
    def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
        q.put(indata.copy())

    def threading_rec(x):
        if x == 1:
            # If recording is selected, then the thread is activated
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=record_audio)
            t1.start()
        elif x == 2:
            # To stop, set the flag to false
            global recording
            recording = False
            messagebox.showinfo(message="Recording finished")
        elif x == 3:
            # To play a recording, it must exist.
            if file_exists:
                # Read the recording if it exists and play it
                data, fs = sf.read("trial.wav", dtype='float32')
                sd.play(data, fs)
                sd.wait()
            else:
                # Display and error if none is found
                messagebox.showerror(message="Record something to play")

    def record_audio(self):
        # Declare global variables
        global recording
        # Set to True to record
        recording = True
        global file_exists
        # Create a file to save the audio
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Recording Audio. Speak into the mic")
        with sf.SoundFile("trial.wav", mode='w', samplerate=44100,
                          channels=2) as file:
            # Create an input stream to record audio without a preset time
            with sd.InputStream(samplerate=44100, channels=2, callback=callback):
                while recording == True:
                    # Set the variable to True to allow playing the audio later
                    file_exists = True
                    # write into file
                    file.write(q.get())

    # Button to record audio
    record_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Record Audio", command=lambda m=1: threading_rec(m))
    # Stop button
    stop_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Stop Recording", command=lambda m=2: threading_rec(m))
    # Play button
    play_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Play Recording", command=lambda m=3: threading_rec(m))

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        record_btn = QPushButton('Record', self)
        record_btn.move(100, 70)

        stop_btn = QPushButton('Stop', self)
        stop_btn.move(200, 70)

        play_btn = QPushButton('Play', self)
        play_btn.move(300, 70)

        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Someone please help me with this code!

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to answer this in a simple way.
Let's say you have a button like this:

```
def init_UI(self):
    self.sum_button = QPushButton(text='sum')
    self.sum_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.get_sum(int_a, int_b))

def get_sum(self, int_a, int_b):
    return int_a + int_b
```

Comment: Yes, understood the basics. But I want to add that `threading_rec(x)` function in the QPushButton, like I have done it in Tkinter Buttons like this: 
`record_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Record Audio", command=lambda m=1: threading_rec(m))`

`stop_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Stop Recording", command=lambda m=2: threading_rec(m))`

`play_btn = Button(voice_rec, text="Play Recording", command=lambda m=3: threading_rec(m))`

This thing is really confusing me.

Comment: I tried this, but its still not working.
`self.record_btn = QPushButton('Record', self)
        self.record_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.threading_rec(x=1))
        self.record_btn.move(100, 70)`

Comment: Try replacing threads with QThreads